# How to use escape characters in lineinfile ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am writing the ansible play for adding the users.

So far I got this.

```
- name: Add user to sudoers
  hosts: all_hosts
  su: yes
  su_user: root
  tasks:
    - lineinfile: line='worker_temp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh' dest='/etc/sudoers'
```

I am able to add the user which is another task.
I am trying to add the same user in the sudoers file.
It fails

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed here

at   - lineinfile: line="worker_temp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh" dest="/etc/sudoers"
                                                       ^ here
```

I tried by adding escaping quotes, but then it appendsthe folloing line in sudoers file

```
worker_temp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD':' /bin/sh
```

this line has `''` unwanted around `:`

How can I get only

```
worker_temp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you are opposed to the `line=''` syntax, but either way, if you switch to [the formal YAML map syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/lineinfile_module.html#examples) this entire discussion evaporates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only escape quotes if you actually quote a scalar, and in your example the value to the key `linenfile` is not a quoted scalar as this is the value:

```
line='worker_temp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh' dest='/etc/sudoers'
```

(although there are quotes in the scalar, a quoted scalar **needs to start** (and end) with a single or double quote).

Just putting double quotes around that will prevent your parser from mis interpreting the second `:` on that line as a value indicator as well as first:

```
- lineinfile: "line='worker_temp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh' dest='/etc/sudoers'"
```